# Compare the elements in the array to see if there are duplicates in the string

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

Currently, I'm having a problem comparing an array with a string. I have 2 arrays and want to find out if the elements in those 2 arrays are in the string

```
 let resultString = "STEREON10.000 4ailthameGrinreD NOCHIMINNICHNUÖC-LOINHÀ GIAIDACBIET2ty UnOMMOSTCRShitConDONG FlimChineCrJ045 Dòketquásoan: XSHCM goi 7181 8186-8110°593364THUBAY6A7 05-6-2021teIntaiKNInTaiChínhTP.HCM"
 let code_province:[String] = ["xsag", "xsbd", "xsbdi", "xsbl","xsbp",
                           "xsbt", "xsbth", "xscm", "xsct", "xsdl",
                           "xsdlk", "xsdn", "xsdng", "xsdno", "xsdt",
                           "xsgl", "xshcm", "xshg", "xskg", "xskh",
                           "xskt", "xsla", "xsmb", "xsnt", "xspy",
                           "xsqb", "xsqng", "xsqnm", "xsqt", "xsst",
                           "xstg", "xstn", "xstth", "xstv", "xsvl",
                           "xsvt", "xsbri",]
    
    let name_Province:[String] = ["angiang","binhduong","binhdinh","baclieu", "binhphuoc","bentre", "binhthuan", "camau", "cantho", "dalat","daklak", "dongnai", "daNang", "daknong", "dongthap","gialai", "hcm", "haugiang", "kiengiang", "khanhhoa","kontum", "longan", "mienbac", "ninhthuan", "phuyen","quangbinh", "quangNgai", "quangnam", "quangtri", "soctrang","tiengiang", "tayninh", "thuat.hue", "travinh", "vinhlong","vungtau","baria"]
```

Comment: Please add some code which you tried. Also, add what problem are you facing.

Comment: Maybe `let resultStringSplit = resultString.components(separatedBy: " "); let contains = !Set(code_province).intersection(resultStringSplit).isEmpty || !Set(name_Province).intersection(resultStringSplit).isEmpty; print(contains)`?

Comment: You can't expect the community to give you the solution to an algorithm. There's lots of string search algorithms. This isn't actually a problem. It feels like you want someone to do the work for you. Do the work. Start [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String-searching_algorithm). Then implement it. Also to @aheze comment, that won't work because they're asking if a string in one of the 2 arrays is "IN THE STRING." Your comment assumes that the string they're looking for is separated by spaces which was not specified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
let f: (String) -> String? = { resultString.localizedStandardContains($0) ? $0 : nil }
let provincesInResult = code_province.compactMap(f)
let namesInResult = name_Province.compactMap(f)
```

We map the list of things to search for from a list of strings, to nil if not found and the string if found. Then we compact the result to leave us with just a list of the found ones. That may be 0, 1 or more, so consider those possibilities.